# What is the significance of visibility modifiers in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to figure out the exact advantages of using different access modifiers in a program. As far as I've understood, all those functionalities that can be achieved through Object Oriented Programming can be done with procedural programming methodology as well.

And seriously I find no suitable explanation rather than some comparison with so-called "real-life" objects. What I really am wishing to know now is, how do access modifiers play an important role in object oriented programming, that outpace the functions and variables in normal procedural programming?

I'm really getting annoyed and starting to hate OOPS, which for me, is just a methodology that takes in much more steps to achieve a task, that is simpler to achieve with procedural code. If anyone could provide me references, that too would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I only really grasped the benefits & strength of OOP by practicing. Sometimes, practicing is just better. A suggestion : take a simple problem, code it in oriented object and in procedural. Then, add new things to the problem and see how easy / hard it is for both codes to evolve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply bro.But I have already tried doing many programs both in procedural and object oriented, still unable to figure our the egde OOPS have over the other.For example,  I tried writing a simple function accepting database connection details like server_name,username,root and db_name as parameters and having the steps for connecting to a database with those obtained details, and a similar method in object oriented method.I seriously din't find any advantage at all.Please help.

Comment: With regard to your DB example i would say take a look at how obtuse the procedural version of the `mysqli` API is as compared to the OO version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary reason given for the existence of different access modifiers is to ensure that consideration is given for what parts of a program should be able to modify various values. Used properly, they will protect a class from inappropriate attempts to modify values without using the proper channels.

However, there is another reason to do with refactoring, which I learned quite late in my appreciation of OO. Consider this code in the context of a large system:

```
class Spaceship
{
    private function teleport()
    {
    }
}
```

Imagine we need to change this method to add an options parameter: our first task would be to scan the whole codebase to see where it had been used. However, we don't need to in this case: the `private` is a very quick indication that it can only have been called in the same class. This speedy understanding helps us realise that such a change will be minor.

If that method is declared as `protected`, then our job is somewhat larger, since we need to examine the class and all child classes - but nevertheless we immediately know it is not a big a refactoring job as if it were `public`.

---

I would add that OO is one of those things that you just need to practice on until you get that 'Aha!' moment. Even the very textbook approaches will show worked exercises (and, hopefully, encourage the reader to use an OO language to try them). I've built a number of systems that I simply can't imagine doing in a procedural manner, but I can't *prove* that -- that's where experience comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility modifiers, better known as access modifiers determine the access level of a class, class methods (functions) and class variables. It dictates to other parts of code if that part of code can be seen and thus used.

Object oriented programming differs from procedural programming. By explaining this you will come to understand the concept of access levels. With procedural programming, you program top-down and you're able to re-use code by using functions. Depending on the programmer,  the code will be cut up in to smaller parts and stored in various files.

With object oriented programming the logic changes. A class represents something, in most examples they use real-life things like a car/house. A class has properties (class variables) and a class can do something / has some behavior (class methods)

Now with this in mind, here is an example as to why access modifiers are used: class `Car` has properties (class variables) and behaviors (class methods). You can imagine what a car can do: `drive()`, `stop()` and `steer()`. We feel that all other parts of code should be able to use these, so we set the access modifiers for these behaviors to public (which means: access to all).

Meanwhile our `Car` has some hidden behaviors that other parts of the code may not need to know: `shiftGear()`, apparently the `drive()` and `stop()` methods make use of it. We can make `shiftGear()` private (which means: only the `Car` class can use it) so it's hidden from the outside world.